# HorizontalScrollView Getting Images from /drawable folder

Tags: android, image, path, directory, horizontalscrollview

I am using HorizontalScrollView in order to create some Gallery-like option and right now I am getting the images from an folder in the external drive. But I figured that I don't need, also shouldn't do that since the images I wanted to show is predetermined images. So I will simply change the directory to the drawable folder but I am not sure which path to go. So right now I am getting the directory with this: 
`String path1= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();`

I found two more methods for directory retrieval but I am not sure which one to use.

```
String path2 = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

String path3= Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

First one returns `"/mnt/sdcard"`, second returns `"/data"`, third one `"/system"`.

Which one should I use in order to reach /drawable folder inside this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which one should I use in order to reach /drawable folder inside this way?

None of them. Those are all for files on the filesystem. Drawable resources are not files on the filesystem.

Use `getResources().getDrawable()` to retrieve a `Drawable` given its ID (e.g., `R.drawable.foo`).

Comment: Can I retrieve its path? Because I need to manipulate the image to write some text on it (I know I can use a TextView or something but I couldn't find any way to add TextView to HorizontalScrollView).

Comment: @MertToka: "Can I retrieve its path?" -- no, because there is no path. Again, resources are not files. They are entries in a ZIP file. "I couldn't find any way to add TextView to HorizontalScrollView" -- the same way you add your `ImageView` to a `HorizontalScrollView`. `HorizontalScrollView` takes one child and allows it to scroll. That child can contain a `RelativeLayout` (or `FrameLayout`) with a `TextView` layered over the `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks for your sincere answers. I found a way to transform Drawable to Bitmap and that helped me to do what I want. I will work on this in the future but currently I am trying to finish before the deadline.